# Print Python code and output in Canopy?

Tags: python, printing, canopy

What's the best way to print source code and output from Canopy?

I've tried printing from a webpage, but I'm using Chrome and Chrome unlike IE does not offer the ability to adjust the scaling parameter. If I print an IPython notebook, is there a way to insert page breaks so blocks of code aren't cut?

Comment: What about using `ipython nbconvert` to export to latex, then compile to `pdf`?

Comment: Hmm...that's not a bad idea. A bit of a hassle, but at least it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just print the source from canopy by doing file -> Print, to get the output from the ipython notebook you could try using the %logstart functionality to create a log of the input/output to a text document. Here is a link for that: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html
    I hope this helped!